# Download file from hyperlink

Tags: python, http, download, scripting, python-requests

beginner here, Try to write script in Python 3.x that downloads a file after logging into a website everyday. The file is embedded in a hyperlink, and typically when clicked on to download you get the OS popup window asking where to save it. I seem to have everything working, except after it downloads/writes to the file I open the file to find the message, “The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.”, instead of the text of the file I’m expecting to find. At this point I’m thinking it’s probably the hyperlink may be where the problem lies (It changes daily based on the date, so I’ve incorporated a datetime statement to account for it). I've tried using things like BeautifuSoup, and Selenium, and dug though dozens of other posts here but haven't quite found a solution. Although they came close still no cigar. Thoughts?

Code:

```
today = datetime.datetime.now()
todays_file = today.strftime('%Y%m%d')

file_url = 'https://site.url/file.url'
site_url = 'https://site.url'
s = requests.Session()
s.get(site_url)
s.post(site_url,data={'username':’username’,'dept':’dept’,'password':’password’})
the_file = s.get(file_url)
with open(‘file.txt','wb') as f:
     f.write(the_file.content)
```

Comment: You assign a value to `todays_file` but never use that value anywhere... that's likely part of your problem.

Comment: If the URL is dynamic, use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to extract it from the source. It's difficult to guess exactly what is going wrong without knowing the details of the request you are trying to make.

Comment: Use `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` to parse HTML and search element.

Comment: page can use JavaScript and then you can't get it with `requests`.

Comment: Use DevTools in Chrome/Firefox what url is used by browser to download it. It can use JavaScript to generate ulr, it can send extra cookies or it can use hidden form to send url as `POST` with extra data form hidden field.

Comment: If you see `“The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.”` when you download using browser then problem is on server and you can do nothing to repair it and download file.

Comment: wpercy - I didn't include in my post for brevity, however the homepage is: 'https://bbo.efiserv.com/.  How can I check to see if the login request went thru?                   Galen - I'll try using Bs4. I read requests may be better for downloading files than bs4, but could bs4 be used to do both instead?

Comment: I think I figured it out. I stumbled across this post: stackoverflow.com/questions/20119258, and found out that there is an 'action' attribute to my login page. After some quick reading I s.post()'ed to that form instead, and tried getting a protected page and printed that protected page via print(protected_page.text) and I can see the html code from the protected page. Now I need to figure out how to download the file from the hyperlink